# Duvida para Carregar ComboBox de uma conta com a subconta

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, sql-server-2014

Eu fiz um select para buscar uma conta e carregar a sub conta e gostaria da opinião de vocês para ver se é assim que faz se está correto

código

```
    private void cbbConta_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        PlanoContasDTO objPlanoConta = new PlanoContasDTO();

        objPlanoConta.DescricaoPlanoContas = cbbConta.Text;

        objPlanoConta = new PlanoContasModel().PesqContaNome(objPlanoConta);

        int conta = objPlanoConta.CodConta;

        CarregarSubContaCombo(conta);
    }
```

segue as imagens da tela

Escolher a conta consumo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Escolher a subconta da Conta

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

até aqui vai certo esta conta é a R=Receita e não aparece nas despesas

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: infelizmente não ficou claro sua pergunta, talvez se tivesse a imgem ficaria melhor, porém acredito que o erro esteja no index que você está passando como parametro: cbbConta.SelectedIndex + 1; normalmente não precisa somar mais um

Comment: coloquei as imagens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denilson Carlos, tenta tirar o  incremento do cbbConta.SelectedIndex +1.

```
  private void cbbConta_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    codContaSelec = cbbConta.SelectedIndex ;
   // codContaSelec = Convert.ToInt32(conta);
    CarregarSubContaCombo(codContaSelec);
}
```